# access mongoDB record when user is logged in

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In general i want to check if user is logged if so pass mongodb record to all ejs templates

This works
I can acess loggedUser from every template

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.userId) {
        const loggedUser = "logged in"; works
    }
});
```

But i need to check if the user is logged and search for the record if he is

This dosent work

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.userId) {

    // If logged make user available in all templates
    Legend.findById({_id: req.session.userId})
        .exec((err, user) => {
            if (err) return next(err)
            console.log(user); // works. i can see the user
            const loggedUser = user;
            next();
        });
    }
});
```

Btw should i do it this way though ?

Its gonna be used to provide profile information etc...

If im right this way i check if the user is logged in on every request he make ?

Can i somehow save the object when he log in untill the session expires / logout ?

Thanks to everyone that tries to help me !!

Comment: You should manage user data in your authenticate middleware and store user data in req.session.user

Comment: Thanks its working now. btw is there a way to pass req.session.user to every template automaticly if user is logged in ?

Comment: You are using pug or ejs template engine?

Comment: Ok, i found solution :)
http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals
`res.locals` object is avaliable in all templates but only in scope of one user/session

Comment: ty so much man i banged my head on this one ... first time i use sessions